# ngOnChanges not firing when same value is updated again

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a property in my appComponent.ts:

```
this._userMessage
```

Then sending it to childComponent through:

```
<child-component [p_sUserMessage]='_userMessage'></child-component>
```

In childComponent.ts:

```
@Input() p_sUserMessage: string = '';
ngOnChanges(): void {
 console.log(this.p_sUserMessage);
}
```

Now the issue i am facing is:

- If i send 'hi' ngOnChanges is fired.
- Now, if again 'hi' is send ngOnChanges is not fired.

Comment: Its not supposed to be, the input didnt change.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method through which my childComponent can be notified.

Comment: Depends on the exact use case. You could use shared service approach (i.e. emit and subscribe to observables) or potentially use ngDoCheck() method but like I said depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Solved : I send 'hi'+counter, so its unique every time.

Comment: As it says ngOnChanges will fire only if the value gets changed. To manually fire it. Change the reference of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following solution

```
this._userMessage=3;
   setTimeout((() => {
    this._userMessage = null; 
   }).bind(this), 300);


<child-component [p_sUserMessage]='_userMessage'></child-component>


@Input() p_sUserMessage: string = '';
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes["p_sUserMessage"]!=undefined) 
  {
     if (changes["p_sUserMessage"].currentValue!=null)
     {
     console.log(changes["p_sUserMessage"].currentValue);
     }
  }
}
```

If i again assign this._userMessage=3, then ngOnChanges again will be complete